# Applescript : Getting List of Id's of Visible windows ( windows shown on the desktop )

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to get the **list of visible windows**, i.e **the windows which are shown on the desktop and not minimized**.

So, far I have this script which gives me the correst list of processes which are running and have a windows associated with it. But I am not able to get the id's of visible windows associated with these processes.

Here's the script :

```
set visibleWindows to ""
set message to ""

tell application "System Events"
    set listOfProcesses to (name of every process where background only is false)
    repeat with visibleProcess in listOfProcesses
        try
            tell process visibleProcess to set visibleWindows to visibleWindows & (id of windows whose visible is true)
        on error someError
            set message to "Some error occured :" & someError
        end try
    end repeat
end tell

return {visibleWindows, listOfProcesses, message}
```

You can try this in script editor but its always giving a empty list.

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you try to get properties of window of process, there are unfortunately very few properties : position, size, type of window and name. no id and no visible flag ! Your script tries to get Id of the window, but this property does not exists, it generates error, but you can't see it in the try bloc !

Answer (score 0):

This script works just fine:

```
set windowsInDock to {}
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with this_app in (get processes whose background only is false) --get applications with 1+ window
        set windowsInDock to windowsInDock & (get windows of this_app whose value of its attribute "AXMinimized" is true)
    end repeat
end tell
return windowsInDock
```

Courtesy of jackjr300.